# PostgreSQL update array with subquery data

Tags: postgresql

Got following SQL, `category_ids` is `array` type, trying to update its value with subquery data, looks like `cc.id` doesn't work here. thanks!

```
update product 
set category_ids = '{cc.id}'
from category cc where cc.location = 'USA';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the array constructor:

```
... SET category_ids = ARRAY[cc.id]
```

In your query, `cc.id` is part of a string literal and is taken, erm, literally.